# How to extract netcdf data in python? (point boundary)

Tags: python, extract, gis, image-segmentation

I am beginner of python.

I have **geo_em_ys.d01.nc** data and this file has many variables,

I want extract data from basin boundary using python.

**LM(Point boundary)** is array and has (lon, lat).

I plot the LANDMASK from nc file and basin points.

[image]

I want the data of the internal nc file stacked on the points.

The plot code is as follows.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import netCDF4 as nc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Point

# Input file paths
nc_path = 'geo_em_ys.d01.nc'

# Open NC file
nc_dataset = nc.Dataset(nc_path, 'r')
landmask = nc_dataset.variables['LANDMASK'][0]  # Remove the first dimension

# Get coordinate information
nc_lat = nc_dataset.variables['XLAT_M'][:]
nc_lon = nc_dataset.variables['XLONG_M'][:]

# Adjust coordinate dimensions
nc_lat = np.squeeze(nc_lat)
nc_lon = np.squeeze(nc_lon)

# Create GeoDataFrame from LM
geometry = [Point(lon, lat) for lon, lat in LM]
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=geometry, crs=crs)

# Create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

# Plot landmask
ax.imshow(landmask, extent=(nc_lon.min(), nc_lon.max(), nc_lat.min(), nc_lat.max()), cmap='Greens', origin='lower')

# Plot points from LM
gdf.plot(ax=ax, color='red')

# Set axis labels
ax.set_xlabel('Longitude')
ax.set_ylabel('Latitude')

# Show entire area
ax.set_xlim(nc_lon.min(), nc_lon.max())
ax.set_ylim(nc_lat.min(), nc_lat.max())

# Add title
plt.title('Landmask with LM Overlay')

# Show plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: not sure if it matters, but what is `LM`?  note that this site isn't designed to be a code writing service, it would help to show what you're tried, and what the constraints are on the data?  e.g. it looks like the data is on a regularly sampled grid, if so you might have luck using a "flood filling" algorithm.  also, I'm not sure how `netcdf` is a relevant tag, where the data comes from often makes little impact on the algorithm choice in segmentation (unless maybe the data is so big it couldn't be performed in RAM, which doesn't appear to be the case here)

Comment: have updated the tags to ones that seem more relevant, hopefully it'll get noticed by somebody who can make better suggestions now